# Can I get the hex file from an Arduino without the .ino code

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, hex

I have a CNC router table that came into my local makerspace. The board looks like it has some standard parts, but also has some parts I don't recognize. At the heart of it is an Arduino Uno. I would like to get the code from the UNO, as a back up. I will have to do testing on this board, but I don't want to overwrite something I don't have a back up of.

is there a way to get the firmware off of the arduino, without having the ino files that generated it?

(This is a standard function on many other platforms such as PIC, I just don't know how to do it in Arudino. I am assuming the functionality also exists.)

Comment: cool story bro, show me.

Comment: the hex file is the code. your MCU runs. if I had the hex file, I wouldnt need the source code, I could upload it to the MCU. I can do that with avrdude, or whatever, Im sure arduno code can do it too.

Comment: here is some talk about it https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61079/is-it-possible-to-extract-code-from-an-arduino-board

Comment: lol nice. Here is some talk about it, no solution, and a link to a 404d page. I think I almost have it figured out one my own, though. ... I think I can get avrdude to do it.

Comment: yes, avrdude is the program ... there should be command line help that may include an example

Answer (score 4):

Cool I got it using avrdude.
$ `avrdude -c arduino -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 9600 -p m328p -U  flash:r:CNCArdunio.hex:i`

```
> -c the platform (basically)
> -P the port where your harware is. 
> -b the baudrate.
> -p the chip architecture.
> -U momory type flash  :r option to read to file  :i option to format into Intel HEX.
```

caveats.Upon closer inspection this is either a very early model UNO, or a cheap clone. It comes up at /dev/ttyUSB0, and required that I press the reset button shortly before sending the avrdude command, else it resulted in

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

Comment: I just thought of another way to do it, using an ardunio as an ISP, (in circiut programmer? wut?) but Im not sure it would work right using this board, and my other authentic Ardunio boards. and it wouldnt give you a file, you would simply make a clone.

Comment: You might also need to read the mcu's eeprom using the same command, but with `eeprom:r:eeprom.eep:i` (I believe).